# Topological proof for the unsolvability of the quintic

Tags: algebraic-topology, quintics

Sorry, but in order to ask the question, you will have to view this video
http://drorbn.net/dbnvp/AKT-140314.php.
Here a topological proof for the unsolvability of the quintic is given, based on ideas of Vladimir Arnold. It's amazing because it does not require Galois Theory! And the proof takes only about 15 minutes in the video. (min 6 - min 22)

Here is my question: At min 7:10 Dror Bar-Natan removes all coefficients which lead to multiple roots, and says something like "It's a codimension 1 thing that we remove".
This is not quite clear to me. What does that mean?

Unfortunately I have not found an exposition of this proof, which is written down in a paper or a book, and which is as clear and easy as the exposition is this this video. If you have a reference here, please let me know!

Here are some more references I have found:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeRXVL6qPk4
- [https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/abel.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/abel.pdf)
- https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmna/1471875703
- https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/394/ArnoldQuintic.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00972.pdf
- Mathematical Omnibus, Dmitry Fuchs, Lecture 5

Comment: Are you asking what codimension $1$ means, or why this set is codimension one, or why it doesn't matter that we remove it (or potentially all of these questions)?

Comment: All of these questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a submanifold of dimension $k$ inside an (ambient) manifold of dimension $n$, we define its codimension as $n-k$. Now you know that the discriminant as a function on $\mathbb{C}^6$ is given by some function (choose your favourite formula, mine is the Vandermonde determinant), but any formula you use should be smooth, and it gives you a function $\mathbb{C}^6 \to \mathbb{C}$. The "bad" points are where the discriminant is $0$ and you can check that $0$ is a regular value, so $f^{-1}(0)$ is something $5$-(complex) dimensional i.e. something codimension $1$. As for why it didn't matter, I can't really say anything besides I didn't see any issue in throwing out these points in the ensuing discussion (which is probably what Bar-Natan meant you'll see it doesn't matter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question to that, and one remark. Question: Can you please explain this "...you can check that 0 is a regular value, so −1(0) is something 5-(complex) dimensional". Remark: I think the reason he removes this set, has someting to do with this: The paths (commutators) in the coefficient space shall induces permutations of the roots in the space of solutions. Therefore we must assume that the roots are distinct.

Comment: Yes that's precisely why he removes it. I was providing the reason why he calls it something codimension $1$. In general the discriminant tests for multiple roots (another way to see this is to consider the gcd of a polynomial and its formal derivative, I forget how exactly), and so the set $f^{-1}(0)$ is exactly the set where you don't have distinct roots.

Comment: As for the question, have you done any differential topology, or are you familiar with the implicit function theorem? Let me give a concrete example. Suppose you were dealing with a quadratic, so our discriminant is $f(a,b,c) = b^2-4ac$ which is a function from $\mathbb{C}^3 \to \mathbb{C}$. Then $Df = [-4c \, \, \,  2b \, -4a]$. A regular point is a point where $Df \neq 0$ and its value is a regular value. In particular, $0$ is a regular value (except at $(0,0,0)$) and so away from here, $f^{-1}(0)$ is a manifold of codimension $1$.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation!